# Custom string input in stringstream

Tags: c++, stream, c++14, stringstream

I'm writing a program that takes a string, and extracts three numbers from said string. The code below displays the working program using a predefined string. I can't seem to figure out how to get the string from the user instead. I tried `stringstream iss(str)` declaring the string inside the main function, but that didn't work.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int T,j;
    int X,Y,K;
    string s;
        stringstream iss("134 513 515");
    cin>>T;
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        iss>>X>>Y>>K;
        cout<<X<<endl<<Y<<endl<<K<<endl;
        int count=((X+Y)/K);
        if(count%2==0)
        cout<<"Chef ";
        else
        cout<<"Paja ";

    }
    cin>>j;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Like `cin >> X >> Y >> K;`?

Comment: Since the input is space separated, I have to store the numbers in a string first. Can't just use ```cin>>X>>Y>>K```.

Comment: `>>` works with spaces, how woul you distinguish between two consecutive numbers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the string using **getline** then passe it to **stringstream** :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int T,j;
    int X,Y,K;
    string s;
    cin>>T;
    cin.ignore();
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        getline(cin, s);
        stringstream iss(s);
        iss>>X>>Y>>K;
        cout<<X<<endl<<Y<<endl<<K<<endl;
        int count=((X+Y)/K);
        if(count%2==0)
        cout<<"Chef ";
        else
        cout<<"Paja ";

    }
    cin>>j;
    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget `cin.ignore()` to flush cin buffer after `cin>>T;`